# NSMutableurlrequest http headerparameter containing newline gets lost

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rest, http-headers, nsurlrequest

as the title says, can't get it to work...

Nothing strange about the code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self prepareRequest:inUrl];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", note] forHTTPHeaderField:NOTE];
....
[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];
```

So, this all works fine, and it arrives at my tomcat java spring service fine. EXCEPT for if the "note" string contains newline characters! looks fine when i debuglog in the client, but on my server the parameter is NULL.

Not sure if i need to urlencode or escape something?

Anybody have any pointers? Thankful for input.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use correct mode when you send data to the server.

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

The default HTTP method is “GET”

Update:

Here is how I would generally send data to the server. The parameters may vary depending on your content type.

```
    NSData* data = [bodyString NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: Hmm, ok. I put all my parameters as request addvalue as above. All my spring-service server methods are configured as GET so older versions of iphone/android will send using that... Can i continue sending all params as "forhttpheaderfield" or do i need to put the "note" value in the post body?

Comment: Not sure what other parameters you use. Generally data should be send via body using POST method. See the update. HTTP header fields should contain supporting info.